# Which is the cleaner way to get a Python @property as a list with particular conditions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

Now I have the source code above:

```
class Stats(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._pending = []
        self._done = []

    @property
    def pending(self):
        return self._pending
```

The way those lists are filled is not important for my question.

The situation is that I'm getting a sublist of these lists this way:

```
stats = Stats()
// code to fill the lists
stats.pending[2:10]
```

The problem here is that I expect to get as many elements as I retrieved.
In the example above I expect a sublist that contains 8 elements (10-2).

Of course, actually I'll get less than 8 elements if the list is shorter.

So, what I need is:

- When the list has enough items, it returns the corresponding sublist.
- When the list is shorter, it returns a sublist with the expected length, filled with the last elements of the original lists and a default value (for example None) for the extra items.

This way, if I did:

```
pending_tasks = stats.pending[44:46]
```

And the pending list only contains 30 elements, it should returns a list of two default elements, for example: [None, None]; instead of an empty list ([]) which is the default behaviour of the lists.

I guess I already know how to do it inside a normal method/function, but I want to do it in the most clean way, trying to follow the @property approach, if possible.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You do know? (I mean how to do it in an ordinary method?) How? How can you make the attribute resolution mechanics sense that after the attribute is resolved there will be a slicing operation? I can only think of using a proxy object, but that may get messy. I'm asking out of mere curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to do because the slicing operation is what you want to modify, and that happens after the original list has been returned by the `property`. It's not impossible though, you'll just need to wrap the regular list with another object that will take care of padding the slices for you. How easy or difficult that will be may depend on how much of the list interface you need your wrapper to implement. If you only need indexing and slicing, it's really easy:

```
class PadSlice(object):
    def __init__(self, lst, default_value=None):
        self.lst = lst
        self.default_value

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = getitem(self.lst, index)
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            expected_length = (index.stop - index.start) // (index.step or 1)
            if len(item) != expected_length:
                item.extend([default_value] * (expected_length - len(item)))
        return item
```

This code probably won't work right for negative step slices, or for slices that don't specify one of the end points (it does have logic to detect an omitted step, since that's common). If this was important to you, you could probably fix up those corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy. How would the object (list) you return know how it will be sliced later? You could subclass `list`, however, and override `__getitem__` and `__getslice__` (Python2 only):

```
class L(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return [list(self)[i] if 0 <= i < len(self) else None for i in xrange(key.start, key.stop, key.step or 1)]
        return list(self)[key]
    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        return self.__getitem__(slice(i, j))
```

This will pad all slices with `None`, fully compatible with negative indexing and steps `!= 1`. And in your property, return an `L` version of the actual list:

```
@property
def pending(self):
    return L(self._pending)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new class, which is a subclass of `list`. Then you can overload the `__getitem__` magic method to overload `[]` operator to the appropriate behavior. Consider this subclass of `list` called `MyList`:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Modify index [] operator"""

        result = super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index)

        if isinstance(index, slice):
            # Get sublist length.
            if index.step: # Check for zero to avoid divide by zero error
                sublist_len = (index.stop - index.start) // index.step
            else:
                sublist_len = (index.stop - index.start)

            # If sublist length is greater (or list is shorter), then extend
            # the list to length requested with default value of None
            if sublist_len > len(self) or index.start > len(self):
                result.extend([None for _ in range(sublist_len - len(result))])

        return result
```

Then you can just change the `pending` method to return a `MyList` type instead of `list`.

```
class Stats(object):
    @property
    def pending(self):
        return MyList(self._pending)
```

Hopefully this helps.